# Separate matching value by hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

code:

```
var finArr = [];
data.forEach(function (line) {
    if (line.toString().indexOf(text) !== -1){
       finArr= finArr.concat(line);
       //console.log( finArr)
    }
})
```

console:

```
[
"59191", "TypeAV - Canada", "Available", 
"422129", "TypeAA - Italy", "Available", 
"959191", "TypeBB - USA", "N/A", 
"6D968C", "TypeAV - Canada", "Available"
]
```

My question is, how do I remove the part after the hyphen (`-`) in each second value?

The expected result is

```
[
"59191", "TypeAV", "Available", 
"422129", "TypeAA", "Available", 
"959191", "TypeBB", "N/A", 
"6D968C", "TypeAV", "Available"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to `map` over the nested arrays and return only the first element of a split on ' - '.

```
var finArr = [];
data.forEach(function (line) {
  finArr = finArr.concat(line.map(function (el) {
    return el.split(' - ')[0];
  }));
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cu8zztpd/2/)

You can also replace `forEach` with `reduce`.

```
var finArr = data.reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p.concat(c.map(function (el) {
    return el.split(' - ')[0];
  }));
}, []);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qht52moq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var data = [["59191","TypeAV - Canada","Available"],["422129","TypeAA - Canada","Available"]], result = [];

data.forEach(function(a) {
  a.map(function(b) {
    b.includes('-') ? result.push(b.split(' - ')[0]) : result.push(b);
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. The RUN CODE does not show results.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the vale of `line[1]` using `line[1] = line[1].split('-')[0]` in `forEach` like following.

```
var data = [["59191", "TypeAV - Canada", "Available"], ["422129", "TypeAA - Canada", "Available"]];
var finArr = [];
data.forEach(function (line) {
    if (line.toString().indexOf('-') !== -1) {
        line[1] = line[1].split('-')[0].trim();
        finArr = finArr.concat(line);
    }
})
console.log(finArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` function and take the first half.

```
element.split(" - ")[0];
```

Example

```
"One thing - two things".split[" - "][0]; // "One thing"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I know the `split(" - ")[0]` is the way. But how do I do it in `finArr.concat(line);` ? +10

Comment: is that `line` just a string? IF so, then split that string by commas - `var splittedLine = line.split[","]`. Then concat splittedLine[0], splittedLine[1].split(" - ")[0] and splitedLine[2]

Comment: "`One thing - two things".split[0]` is "One thing" is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for noticing Andy

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, you could iterate and change the result to the first element of splitting.

```js
var array = [["59191", "TypeAV - Canada", "Available"], ["422129", "TypeAA - Italy", "Available"], ["959191", "TypeBB - USA", "N/A"], ["6D968C", "TypeAV - Canada", "Available"]];
array = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        r.push(b.split(' - ')[0]);
    });
    return r;
}, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Nina, look at the expected output.

Comment: @andy, thank you, i thought, that i was missing something :) please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use regex for this task

Seeing your JSON data it seems like only the second value will have a hyphen. So using regex you can remove the string `- xyz` ike below..

`data = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(data).replace(/-\w+/g,""));`

Now you have removed the unwanted text, follow this with your existing Loop logic and you must get the desired output.